# Arch linux [Armv7] docker install

Tags: linux, docker, archlinux

I've installed Docker via `pacman -S docker`, but when I'm trying to run Dockerd it says

> INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 9792 
>   WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
>   FATA[0001] Your Linux kernel version 3.4.39 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.

I'm trying to run it with `DOCKER_NOWARN_KERNEL_VERSION=1` and it gives me

> INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 9810 
>   WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
>   ERRO[0001] [graphdriver] prior storage driver devicemapper failed: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed 
>   Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed

What did I do wrong?!.. 
Running this on Orang Pi PC
Thanks

Comment: Wasn't 3.4 released in like 2012 or something? Is something preventing you from just updating your kernel?

Comment: @Roope `pacman -Syu` says me it's the final version nowadays

Comment: @Roope I'll look for other kernels in AUR

Comment: @Roope it says me that "4.10.10-1-ARCH" is installed, but even after reinstalling and reboot `uname -r` still show me 3.4.39. Help, please...

Answer (score 0):

I've found, that kernel > 4.0 does exist for this Pi. I've installed Armbian on my Orange Pi PC and **I'm sure that it the best thing you could install**. I goes with linux-4.10.3 on the board and works fine.